# static pointer initialization is reset 'after' initialization

Tags: c++, boost, static-members

I have two classes like this:

```
class BasicLogger {
//...
}

class Logger {
public:
    static boost::shared_ptr<Logger> log_;
    static BasicLogger &log(const std::string &key){
        if (!log_) {
            log_.reset(new Logger());
        }
        return (*log_)(key);//calls operator()
    }
    virtual BasicLogger & operator()(const std::string &key);
    virtual ~Logger();
};
//definition of static member
boost::shared_ptr<Logger> Logger::log_;
```

Then somewhere in the code I use the above classes by :

```
namespace{
    BasicLogger & csv = Logger::log("trip.csv");
}
```

My problem started when I noticed that `~Logger()` is never called, so I started debugging.
The control first rushed to `BasicLogger & csv = Logger::log("trip.csv");` line which would eventually initialized my `static shared pointer` variable `Logger::log_`

THEN
the line `boost::shared_ptr<Logger> Logger::log_;` is executed which will reset `log_` back to `null` !. 
I expect the shared pointer `Logger::log_` go out of acope at the end of my application and execute some logic by invoking `~Logger()` but it is never called.

Am I following a wrong/bad practice? Any Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) (also some nice info on https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors)

The most convenient way to "fix" it is to

- use function local static instead of globals
- use file-locals static (inside a single translation unit, the initialization order is defined)

So:

```
static boost::shared_ptr<Logger>& getLog() { 
    static boost::shared_ptr<Logger> log_;

    if (!log_) {
        log_.reset(new Logger());
    }

    return log_;
};
static BasicLogger &log(const std::string &key){
    return (*getLog())(key);//calls operator()
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dbe5af6df6cf5a3)**

---

That said, it looks like you might really want to keep a `weak_ptr` there.

Comment: Haha... some trailers from the cool link yo sent ... `If you think it's "exciting" to play Russian Roulette with live rounds in half the chambers, you can stop reading here`.... `Enjoy flipping burgers at McDonalds` ... made my day, thank you

Comment: when I use shared pointer, it means I have heard of weak_ptr s also. but I dont know why I can't find a use case for them. can you help a bit more on this one? perhaps you can continue your answer as Part II.

Comment: And one more thing just to make sure, you shifted the static variable `log_` to the getter function `getLog()`. will there be anything wrong if I dont use a getter method and keep the static variable inside the user (`log()`) ?

Comment: @rahman no difference there, just as long as you don't use namespace/global statics